# How do I modify the POST data with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to query  the whole month data **2015-6**

I found every **POST** request will send the following two params

```
MarketMonth1   2015-6
MarketDay1 17
```

one is for year-month, the other is for day.

It is too verbosed and time consuming to set the value mimic the mouse clicking on calendar.

I wonder if I can inject/modify the POST params when sending the POST request.

Comment: You can possibly modify the input without interacting with date calender and trigger the change manually then post.

Comment: Check this answer it's help top post data with selenium .
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795281/10940859

Answer (score 2):

You can not do it directly with `WebDriver`, but you can direct all your traffic thru a proxy and modify all you need before sending it server. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654141/selenium-webdrivers-load-page-without-any-resources/19654899#19654899) about setting up browsermob.